# How to make special XML Node?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am working in C# and i have no idea to make an xml node with spaces.

It shoult look like the following:

```
<Test1 unitTest="KGM">1234<Test1/>
```

Comment: Do you mean attribure?

Comment: Yes I think this is what I am looking for. Did not know which word I should search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to use Google?

```
 XmlElement test1 = doc.CreateElement("Test1");
 test1.SetAttribute("unitTest", "KGM");
 test1.InnerText = "1234";
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I need.
Will accept in 8 mins

Comment: @xileb0 Glad to have been of help

Comment: I used google, but I did not know the word attribute. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here a simplified solution to what you seem to be asking for:

```
using System.Xml;

...

//Create XML Document
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

//Crate a node and add it to document
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Test1");
xmlDoc.AppendChild(node);

//Create an attribute and add it to node
XmlAttribute attrib = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("unitTest");
attrib.Value = "KGM";
node.Attributes.Append(attrib);

//Add text content to node
node.InnerText = "1324";
```